# How do i create a file on a network client from a network web server

Tags: php, windows, file, ubuntu, client

I have a webserver set up on a business network. I am using php to create a file and I want to write it to a local client shared folder also on the network. When I ping from the client I get a response from the webserver. When I ping from the webserver I get a response from the client. Here's my code. I am getting a permissions error. Any ideas what could cause that? Is the path correct? How do I formulate the path?

```
    $fileName = "\\\\7PD01-2012.payday.local\\PTBurnJobs\\file.txt";
    var_dump($fileName);
    if (($myfile = fopen($fileName, "w+")) === false) { //open the file
           //if unable to open throw exception
           throw new RuntimeException("Could Not Open File Location.");
    }
    foreach($arr as $line){
           fwrite($myfile, $line . PHP_EOL);

    }
    fclose($myfile);
```

Would it be more prudent to create the file on the webserver and then transfer it to the client? How would I do that?

Comment: Are you getting anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a permissions error, then you will need to check that the user your php script/webserver is running under has write permissions in the client folder.

A question for you:
How do you know you are getting a permissions error? The code above does not check *why* something failed, only that it failed.

If you are getting a permissions error, then it sounds like a successful connection is being made, and you're at least attempting to transfer the file successfully, only getting blocked by your ACL layer.

Comment: Warning: fopen(\\7PD01-2012.payday.local\PTBurnJobs\file.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/CDprinter/processor.php on line 139

Comment: fopen is on line 139

Comment: Yes, your webserver user is blocked from writing to the network location, that needs to be fixed.